# CSS modules pass property as styles property

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules

I'd like to add a custom class to my `Button` component in app I'm learning react on.

In my `Form.js` I have

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Button from './Button';
import styles from '../css/LoginElements.css';

class Form extends Component {
  render() {

    const click = this.props.onSubmit;

    return(
      <div className={styles.form}>
        <Button
          name="Register"
          className="register"
          onClick={click} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

And in the `Button.js` I have

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from '../css/LoginElements.css';

const Button = ({name, onClick, className }) => (
  <div className={styles.wrapper}>
    <div className="field">
      <div className={className? styles.className : styles.button} onClick={onClick}>{name}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Button;
```

The problem is that `styles.className` will work if I put `.className` in my `LoginElements.css` file, and not `.register`, as I would like.

What do I need to do to use the class name from the button property as a class? And not just `register` but so that it's like `LoginElements__register__34Kfd` (locally scoped)?

Comment: If you do `className={styles[className]}` then you'll get the `.register` class from `LoginElements.css`. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm not reading this correctly, but I think the problem is that you're using dot notation to access the className from styles instead of brackets.

Can you update Button.js to

`<div className={className? styles[className] : styles.button}`

Dot notation will not recognize `className` as a variable but instead will treat it literally as the property name

Comment: That's it! I forgot to treat it like a regular object! Thanks!